# ¿Cómo hacer UPDATE a varios valores al mismo tiempo desde otra tabla de MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Lo que hago es actualizar valores de tabla que coincidan en cuanto al ID con valores de otra tabla. Mi código es muy lento y largo, no había una forma de hacer UPDATE a los 4 valores una vez que se ha encontrado el ID en vez de buscar uno por uno? Tengo este código actualmente:

```
UPDATE lithuania_customers_2016, lithuania_customers_history

SET

lithuania_customers_2016.crm_status = (
SELECT lithuania_customers_history.crm_status
FROM lithuania_customers_history
WHERE lithuania_customers_2016.customer_db_id = lithuania_customers_history.customer_db_id
ORDER BY crm_upload_date DESC
LIMIT 1
),

lithuania_customers_2016.crm_nad = (
SELECT lithuania_customers_history.crm_nad
FROM lithuania_customers_history
WHERE lithuania_customers_2016.customer_db_id = lithuania_customers_history.customer_db_id
ORDER BY crm_upload_date DESC
LIMIT 1
),


lithuania_customers_2016.crm_account_status = (
SELECT lithuania_customers_history.crm_account_status
FROM lithuania_customers_history
WHERE lithuania_customers_2016.customer_db_id = lithuania_customers_history.customer_db_id
ORDER BY crm_upload_date DESC
LIMIT 1
),


lithuania_customers_2016.crm_notes = (
SELECT lithuania_customers_history.crm_notes
FROM lithuania_customers_history
WHERE lithuania_customers_2016.customer_db_id = lithuania_customers_history.customer_db_id
ORDER BY crm_upload_date DESC
LIMIT 1
)


WHERE lithuania_customers_2016.customer_db_id = lithuania_customers_history.customer_db_id
AND lithuania_customers_history.user_id = '100011';
```

Os lo agradezco.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes simplicar tu *query* quitando las subconsultas y creando un `UPDATE FROM`:

```
UPDATE lithuania_customers_2016, lithuania_customers_history
SET
    A.crm_status = B.crm_status,
    A.crm_nad = B.crm_nad
    A.crm_account_status = B.crm_account_status
    A.crm_notes = B.crm_notes
FROM lithuania_customers_2016 A, lithuania_customers_history B
    ON lithuania_customers_2016.customer_db_id = lithuania_customers_history.customer_db_id
WHERE B.user_id = '100011';
```

Comment: Gracias, pero necesito hacer UPDATE con valores que contienen la última fecha (cómo puedes ver en mi código aplico ORDER BY crm_upload_date DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: Bueno, mas o menos me ha ayudado a solucionar el problema.